# Issue loading JSON data into JS object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

So I've been looking around but have yet to find a solution to my issue. I'll simplify my project to the extent of asking my question - as I'm new to JS and JSON.

ERROR I'm receiving:

```
(node:4486) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'default.json'
```

I created a temp function while de-bugging this to verify the directory, and check that my desired file exists.

Im wanting to load in default parameters from a JSON file for a simulation and set them to an object in a function. Where I am having an issue, is reading in the file. - keep getting error that file is not open.

File System:

```
    Folder/
        main.js
        default.json
```

JSON:

```
{
    "deltaTime": 0.1,
    "maxDuration": 10,
    "degreeFreedom": 4
}
```

Code:

```
// Import the filesystem module 
const fs = require('fs'); 

// Get the current filenames in the directory 
getCurrentFilenames(); 

// Function to get current filenames in directory 
function getCurrentFilenames() { 

  console.log("\nCurrent filenames:"); 
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(file => { 
    console.log(file); 
  }); 
  console.log("\n"); 

  console.log("-------------------"); 
  let defaultFile = 'default.json';


  if(fs.existsSync(defaultFile) == 'false') {
    console.log(" defaultFile doesnt exist");
  }
  else {
    // main object
    let simParameters = {};

    // verifying my desired file name exists
    console.log(" defaultFile exists");

    // calling the load function to load file and set to object
    loadFile(defaultFile, simParameters);

    // printing object
    console.log(simParameters);
  }
} 

async function loadFile(filename, simParameters) {
    // read in json object from file
    simParameters = await jsonReader(filename);
}

// read a JSON file and return the contents
async function jsonReader(filename) {
  console.log(filename);
    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, text) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(JSON.parse(text));
        });
    });

    return data;
}
```

Output:

```
Current filenames:
default.json
main.js
-------------------
defaultFile exists
default.json
{}
(node:4486) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'default.json'
```

From the output, I can see that the file exists, but its not setting the data to my object.

Comment: Obviously it's saying I need to "open" the file before I can 'fs.readFile', what step am I missing? Do I need to "fs.open(filename, 'r')" in my reader function ?

Comment: Do you mind using [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) in your project?

Comment: And why do you need `getCurrentFilenames()` function? Are you using that just to make sure that json file doesn't exist? Figuring that out will reveal how things can be refactored

Comment: Yes M.A. its just a temp function to verify the files in the directory

Comment: can you check my answer and let me know if it worked for you? You probably won't need `getCurrentFilenames()` at all.

Comment: @M.AShahbazi I think this is on the right track. However, it still is not parsing the file and setting it to the object. Its only returning the default values in the 'catch'. I changed the values in the file to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly `require('<whatever-filename>.json')`, but either use an absolute path or a relative path, if not, node is going to look in `node_modules` directory:

```
// Import the filesystem module 
const fs = require('fs'); 

// Get the current filenames in the directory 
getCurrentFilenames(); 

// Function to get current filenames in directory 
function getCurrentFilenames() { 

  console.log("\nCurrent filenames:"); 
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(file => { 
    console.log(file); 
  }); 
  console.log("\n"); 

  console.log("-------------------"); 
  let defaultFile = './default.json'; // Mind the './' at the beginning


  if(fs.existsSync(defaultFile) == 'false') {
    console.log(" defaultFile doesnt exist");
  }
  else {
    // main object
    let simParameters = {};

    // verifying my desired file name exists
    console.log(" defaultFile exists");

    // calling the load function to load file and set to object
    loadFile(defaultFile, simParameters);

    // printing object
    console.log(simParameters);
  }
} 

async function loadFile(filename, simParameters) {
    // read in json object from file
    simParameters = await jsonReader(filename);
    console.log(simParameters)
}

// read a JSON file and return the contents
async function jsonReader(filename) {
    console.log(filename);
    const data = require(filename)
    return data;
}
```

Comment: The file is just a default file, but I need to be able to load in parameters from any file. End game is to allow a customer to load a specified file for their desired simulation parameters. So I don't want to strictly require the default file in the event a customer choose to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a json file using `fs.readFile` or `fs.readFileSync` function.
Returned value will be buffer so in order to use it you need to use `toString()` method.

```
// Import the filesystem module
const fs = require('fs');

// Loads and parses json file
const loadDefaults = (filename) => {
    try {
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filename)
        const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString()
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
    } catch (e) {
        // If default.json file doesn't exist
        return {
            deltaTime: 0.1,
            maxDuration: 10,
            degreeFreedom: 4
        }
    }
}

// Function to get current filenames in directory
function getCurrentFilenames() {
    console.log('\nCurrent filenames:');
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach((file) => {
        console.log(file);
    });
    console.log('\n');

    console.log('-------------------');
    let defaultFile = 'default.json';

    if (fs.existsSync(defaultFile) == 'false') {
        console.log(' defaultFile doesnt exist');
    } else {
        // verifying my desired file name exists
        console.log(' defaultFile exists');

        // calling the load function to load file and set to object
        let simParameters = loadDefaults(defaultFile);

        // printing object
        console.log(simParameters);
    }
}

// Get the current filenames in the directory
getCurrentFilenames();
```

Comment: While investigating this solution, I noticed that the 'loadFile' function is catching an error in the 'try' at 'const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filename)' and kicking it to the 'catch' defaults.